# sql query between time and a DISTINCT column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

my table for a vehicle looks like

```
vehNo   tTime                     odo     
ABC     2013-02-13 10:30:00       80       
ABC     2013-02-12 10:30:00       10      
ABC     2013-02-12 12:30:00       30      
ABC     2013-02-13 01:30:00       40      
ABC     2013-02-13 02:30:00       40 
ABC     2013-02-13 03:30:00       40 
XYZ     2013-02-13 03:33:00       44
ABC     2013-02-13 04:30:00       60 
ABC     2013-02-13 11:30:00       100
```

i can give between time 2013-02-12 10:30:00 and 2013-02-13 10:30:00  (order by time)but how do i get DISTINCT odo  like

```
ABC     2013-02-12 10:30:00       10 
ABC     2013-02-12 12:30:00       30 
ABC     2013-02-13 03:30:00       40         (time being latest, ignoring 1:30 & 2:30)
ABC     2013-02-13 04:30:00       60
ABC     2013-02-13 10:30:00       80
```

im running on MSSql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok with @mark i extended my solution as

```
select vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
from Table_1
where vehNo = 'ABC' and tTime between '2013-02-12 10:30:00' and '2013-02-13 10:30:00'
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
from vehicles
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo
```

Obviously, for the between "2013-02-12 10:30:00 and 2013-02-13 10:30:00" you can add a `where` clause in the middle:

```
select vehNo, max(tTime) as [tTime], odo
from vehicles
where tTime between @start and @end
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo
```

Comment: if i were to select only 'ABC'

Comment: ok got it by where vehNo ='ABC' and tTime between start and end is it rit?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 already supports `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function`. With the help of `ROW_NUMBER()` it ranks the records from a group by specifying the order of the records.

```
WITH latestDate
AS
(
    SELECT vehNo, tTime, odo,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vehNo, odo
                                ORDER BY tTime DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  vehNo, tTime, odo
FROM    latestDate
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adb37/1)

Comment: almost there but how about BETWEEN tTime

Comment: what do you mean between time?

Comment: isn't that just a really complicated way of saying `max(tTime)` over a group?

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree with you `:D` but this will help if there are other columns on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
select vehNo, max(tTime) as tTime, odo
from myTable
group by vehNo, odo
order by vehNo, odo
```

---

```
| VEHNO |               TTIME | ODO |
-------------------------------------
|   ABC | 2013-02-12 10:30:00 |  10 |
|   ABC | 2013-02-12 12:30:00 |  30 |
|   ABC | 2013-02-13 03:30:00 |  40 |
|   ABC | 2013-02-13 04:30:00 |  60 |
|   ABC | 2013-02-13 10:30:00 |  80 |
|   ABC | 2013-02-13 11:30:00 | 100 |
```

Here is [`SQL Fiddle DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bf35/5/0).

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to GROUP BY odo and select the MAX(tTime). Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  vehNO, 
  MAX(tTime) AS tTime,
  MAX(odo) AS odo
FROM vehicle
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```